# Rust deadlocking in Tokio when storing TcpStreams in HashMap

Tags: rust

I will start by saying that yes I am a beginner and I might do a lot of stuff wrong here but it seems like I can not escape the issue with me deadlocking (At least I think this is the issue).

So I am just doing a simple websocket program that really shouldn't do much but

1. Accept connections and without sending to channels (but all sockets one by one) that someone new has connected. Channels would of course be appropriate here but I just want to try explore all parts and starting without channels.
2. Be able to accept a message from a client and broadcast to all other sockets.

I am sure there are some stuff I am doing wrong, but keep in mind that this is just a playground project and I just started learning Rust. And yes there is poor/no error handling. Just playing around...

The code works when I comment out the line, so somewhere in my logic near here is causing the issues. When having it commented out I get broadcasts to all my clients when someone new connects. However, when I include this, it stops working for all new clients once the first one has connected. This is the line which causes it:

```
Server::handle_client_events(clients_clone, id).await;
```

All the code

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::str::from_utf8;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use tokio::{net::TcpListener, net::TcpStream};

use std::error::Error;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Server {
    clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, TcpStream>>>,
}

impl Server {
    async fn start(&self, addr: &str) -> tokio::io::Result<()> {
        let server = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await?;
        println!("Server listning on {}", addr);

        let mut id: usize = 0;
        let mut num_clients: i16 = 0;
        loop {
            let (socket, _) = server.accept().await?;
            num_clients += 1;
            id += 1;
            println!("Clients online: {}", num_clients);

            {
                let mut clients = self.clients.lock().await;
                clients.insert(id, socket);
            }
            Server::handle_connection(self.clients.clone(), id).await;
        }
    }

    async fn handle_client_events(clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, TcpStream>>>, id: usize) {
        let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
        loop {
            //I think this is where I am deadlocking
            let mut clients_guard = clients.lock().await; 
            let socket = clients_guard.get_mut(&id).expect("Client not found");

            match socket.read(&mut buf).await {
                Ok(0) => {
                    println!("Client {} disconnected", id);
                    let mut clients_guard = clients.lock().await;
                    clients_guard.remove(&id);
                    break;
                }
                Ok(_) => {
                    let msg = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf);
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Socket error");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    async fn handle_connection(clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, TcpStream>>>, id: usize) {
        let msg = format!("Client id {} connected\n", id);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            Server::stream_to_all(&clients, msg).await;
            Server::handle_client_events(clients_clone, id).await;
        });
    }

    async fn stream_to_all(clients_clone: &Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, TcpStream>>>, message: String) {
        let mut clients = clients_clone.lock().await;
        for (_id, client) in clients.iter_mut() {
            if client.write_all(message.as_bytes()).await.is_err() {
                println!("Could not send message to client");
            }
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> tokio::io::Result<()> {
    let addr = String::from("127.0.0.1:8080");
    let server = Server {
        clients: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())),
    };
    server.start(&addr).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

I expect to get:
"Client id 1 connected"
when first one connection, then when another one is connecting the first one will get
"Client id 1 connected Client id 2 connected"
in the first connection and in the second
"Client id 2 connected"

So basically you get your own connection and all the new that connects.
I am using nc localhost 8080 to try the connection stuff

Comment: I would think the problem is that once the first client has connected you're in the `socket.read` behind a lock until that client does something (sends a packet or disconnect), and until that happens there's no way for the `start` coroutine to acquire the lock and add new clients attempting to connect.

Comment: Also it looks like the function would deadlock itself if the client closes the connection: within `Ok(0)` you're re-acquiring the lock you already hold, that can not work since you're still holding the lock.

Comment: Oh yea I see that the disconnect have issues with deadlocking itself. And seems like the issue with the other is that it will await an input until it can release its lock. However How can this be solved. I've arranged it in so many different ways but always seems to that if I want to wait for input I have to deadlock it. Appreciate the nice answer!

Comment: What would make the most sense to me is to have each worker task fully responsible for its socket, the socket itself should not be stored in a map nor should it be interacted with by the driver (e.g. `stream_to_all`). Instead the driver should communicate with individual tasks via a channel, or maybe multiple channels, and the task should multiplex between those communication channels and the socket it's responsible for.

Comment: Those channels & co are what get stored in the map, such that the driver can send requests to connected tasks, and get notified of tasks disconnecting (in order to remove them from the map).

Comment: So instead of saving the connection in a map I should move the socket to handle_connection (instead of storing in a HashMap) and spawn channels to communicate through. As for example one channel with all sockets that can broadcast the message when a client connects to everyone else, then send the socket over to handle_client_events. So I'll store the channels instead in a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. It might not be a nice and "appropriate" way to do it but it works as intended now.

My solution was to split the read_half and write_half in two parts (amazing that this was possible btw!) as the listener only needs the read half and the rest needs the write part. This means that I can now store my write part in my hashmap since the writing did not need to obtain any long-lived locks (as the read did which caused the deadlock).

Here is the updated code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::str::from_utf8;
use std::sync::Arc;

use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use tokio::{net::TcpListener, net::TcpStream};

use std::error::Error;
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, ReadHalf, WriteHalf};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Server {
    clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, WriteHalf<TcpStream>>>>,
}

impl Server {
    async fn start(&self, addr: &str) -> tokio::io::Result<()> {
        let server = TcpListener::bind(&addr).await?;
        println!("Server listning on {}", addr);

        let mut id: usize = 0;
        let mut num_clients: i16 = 0;
        loop {
            let (socket, _) = server.accept().await?;
            num_clients += 1;
            id += 1;
            println!("Clients online: {}", num_clients);

            let (read_half, write_half) = tokio::io::split(socket);

            let mut clients = self.clients.lock().await;
            clients.insert(id, write_half);

            self.handle_connection(id, read_half).await;
        }
    }

    async fn handle_client_events(
        clients_clone: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, WriteHalf<TcpStream>>>>,
        mut socket: ReadHalf<TcpStream>,
        id: usize,
    ) {
        let mut buf = vec![0; 1024];
        loop {
            match socket.read(&mut buf).await {
                Ok(0) => {
                    {
                        println!("Client {} disconnected", id);
                        let mut clients_guard = clients_clone.lock().await;
                        clients_guard.remove(&id);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                Ok(_) => {
                    let msg = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buf);
                    Server::stream_to_all(&clients_clone, msg.to_string()).await;
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Socket error");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    async fn handle_connection(&self, id: usize, read_half: ReadHalf<TcpStream>) {
        let msg = format!("Client id {} connected\n", id);

        let clients_clone = self.clients.clone();

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            Server::stream_to_all(&clients_clone, msg).await;
            Server::handle_client_events(clients_clone, read_half, id).await;
        });
    }

    async fn stream_to_all(
        clients_clone: &Arc<Mutex<HashMap<usize, WriteHalf<TcpStream>>>>,
        message: String,
    ) {
        let mut clients = clients_clone.lock().await;
        println!("Broadcasting to {} clients.", clients.len());
        for (_id, client) in clients.iter_mut() {
            if client.write_all(message.as_bytes()).await.is_err() {
                println!("Could not send message to client");
            }
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> tokio::io::Result<()> {
    let addr = String::from("127.0.0.1:8080");
    let server = Server {
        clients: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())),
    };
    server.start(&addr).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is focused on finding solutions to problems, for general advice on code that is already working (somewhat), you'll want to head to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Apart from that: well done on figuring out the issue itself _and_ figuring out a solution which works.

Comment: Sure! Just wanted to give an update regarding the solution.

Comment: And I'm glad you did, it may help another one stuck on a similar issue later on :)